# Dropbox - Transfer files to another account and then delete them from mine

Tags: macos

My husband started using my iPad and added some large files to dropbox.  He now has his own dropbox account on the iPad.  How can we transfer his files to his account on the iPad so that I can delete them from my dropbox account(using Mac OS)? I am no longer using the iPad - he takes it with him for his international work.

As I understand it I can share the files in my account with him so long as I retain them in my account.  I don't want them in my account.  He needs them only in his account.

Comment: Does this work? https://www.dropbox.com/help/389

Answer (score 0):

If you share a folder link with your husband and he opens that link in a web browser while signed into his Dropbox account in the browser then when he clicks the Download link he can choose to add the folder to his Dropbox.

Once the folder is added you should then be able to remove it from your Dropbox account and he can synchronize the newly added files to the iPad.